# Are the calls for determining memory available etc reliable?

Tags: java, memory, runtime

I am using the following calls:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()
Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()
Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()
```

But what I notice about maxMemory is that when I specify 50 gig using the command line option for memory on a machine that has far less memory than this, 50 gig is the figure that shows up from this call. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Yes. The JVM doesn't bother about  *max available* memory as long as *currently available* memory is sufficient. Once the heap size increases, depending on the platform, hell might break loose. From [javaDoc for max memory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#maxMemory()) - *Returns the maximum amount of memory that the Java virtual machine will attempt to use. If there is no inherent limit then the value Long.MAX_VALUE will be returned.* .. **will attempt to use**.

Comment: Thanks. Here's the problem I am facing. I am using a linux machine with plenty of memory but getting out-of-memory errors when I create an array of one million 1k strings, roughly using a gig I thought. If the machine has 16 gig of memory, will it automatically grab this memory or do I need to specify the 16 gig using the cmd line argument which I am trying without success?

Comment: 1. You cannot create an array of size greater than INTEGER.MAX_VALUE. . next, yes you can tell the jvm how much memory to use. . There are options to increase the max available memory

Comment: The number of elements is only one million. Integer max is 2 gig so the size in memory of the array should be less than that.

Comment: Are you using jdk 6 or jdk 5?. are you creating strings on heap or on string constants pool?

Comment: I am using jdk 6. Not that it should matter but the machine is an AWS instance. I can run this simple program to allocate an array of half a million 1k strings without the memory error. Not sure when it hits but 1 million definitely fails no matter how much memory the machine has of what cmd line I specify.

Comment: How are you creating strings? . Are you creating string literals? . Also, have you tried increasing the jvm memory?

Comment: I am appending to a stringbuffer and then turning it into a string. Increasing JVM memory in some way other than specifying it on the command line?